# javascript keypress function

Tags: javascript, keyboard

i thought i had solved this but my basic example seems to not be working. not sure why but i am sure it is a small issue. any help is appreciated.

`<html>`
`<head>`
`</head>`

`<body>`
`<textarea rows="20" cols="61" id="entry" name="entry" class="body_text" wrap="physical">`
`</textarea>`
`</body>`
`</html>`
`<script>`
`function keypress(e){`
`var key_s = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;`
`document.getElementById("entry").innerHTML=key_s;`
`}`
`</script>`

Comment: That's not how you format HTML for Stackoverflow. All you have to do is indent it all by 4 or more spaces.

Comment: thanks will keep this in mind for next post.

Comment: was unaware of this feature. thank you for pointing it out, definitely will do so going forward.

Comment: I actually like this formatting.  This definitely doesn't deserve a downvote. +1 to even it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the keypress event listener to the browser.
That can be done in several ways:

- rename keypress to onkeypress (-> window.onkeypress)
- use addEventListener or attachEvent (IE specific):

  if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('keypress', keypress, false);
  else if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onkeypress', keypress);
  else window.onkeypress = keypress;

What's happening? First, check if the standard way to handle events is available.
If so, use it. Otherwise, use Internet Explorers method.
If you're really using an old browser, use a legacy method.

You should also use 'value' instead of 'innerHTML' on textarea's.